# move boot manager to the hard drive with installed windows

Tags: windows-8, boot

I've got `Windows 8` installed on SSD.

For some reason `Windows Boot Manager` is located on a separate HDD. I am not sure why it happened though.

Is there a way to bring `boot manager` to SSD?